# React Native Text Selectable prop not working

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a Text component which I would like to make selectable. I provided the Text component the selectable prop, however it isn't working. I am pretty sure that it is because I have it nested in a ScrollView and my pressing it is only registering on the scrollview. Any way to get past this?

Can provide a code example if needed.

Comment: Did you try long press to select the text?

Comment: maybe the reason you can't select is your `ScrollView` which is around the text. When clicking u are causing a interactio with the scroll and not with the Text

Comment: by selectable you mean you want to click on the text to do something ? is that is the case just surround your text with pressable or any other callback component and call function on onPress={()=> something()} of that component

Comment: No. I basically have an address that I would like the user to be able to highlight (and copy) so they can paste it elsewhere.